# Pico-8 coroutines are occasionally dead

Tags: lua, pico-8

I was trying to replace a for-loop with coroutines to move the stars:

```
--fine
function _update()
 for c in all(boids) do
  move_boid(c)
 end
end

--broken
function _update()
 for c in all(boids) do
  coresume(cocreate(move_boid),c)
 end
end
```

Notice that a fixed number of stars are frozen (I'm pretty sure the number is fixed):

[image: boids]

But why? How can I handle this? The complete code is on [itch](https://knh190.itch.io/pico-8-boids).

Comment: Wrap the call to `coresume` with an `assert` to catch any possible runtime errors produced by coroutines. Btw, the way it is called now, there's no point in using coroutines, it's only a waste of time.

Comment: @Vald I checked it with `costatus` and `co!=null`, no errors. I need coroutines because each boid takes some calculations that is logically wrong to do it one by one.

Comment: Running coroutine without `yield` somewhere in the middle is like calling a plain function, just takes some more resources. It's not a parallel thread, you won't save time by creating lots of coroutines.

Comment: An interesting quote from lexaloffle's forum: `coroutines seem to yield automatically if PICO-8 runs out of cycles while running the routine. Not sure if this has been documented anywhere`.  In other words, your system is overloaded.  Try to reduce amount of snowflakes.

Comment: Playing a bit with sources. It feels that it's not about exceptions, it's like your model for boids make it stuck because of high boids density. If I reduce the number of boids, then sometimes I see few of them occasionally slowing down to a freeze point, but after few second they continue to move.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yeah I'm aware that fewer boids are fine. Also tried increase the number of boids, and frozen number of boids increased (still, with some portion, a fixed number). @Vlad if you try replace it with `move_boid(c)` it'll be slower. Surely here I'm parallelizing it.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff still no idea how to handle this. Create a table for coroutines and  loop it in `_update`? Seems not working if there're a lot. (but actually, 40 is not large.)

Comment: You're not parallelizing it. If it's true that pico-8 yields coroutines on its own, then you skip some steps in your simulation, making it faster, but incomplete. Coroutines do not run in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @Vald and @Egor's comments. Seems the problem is caused by "too-long coroutines" to finish in a PICO-8 cycle. So the solution is that I store unfinished coroutines in a table and resume them if not finished. But somehow the movement is changed, kinda like "lost frame".

Here's my edited code:

```
function _init()
 -- code
 cors={}
end

function _update()
 for i=1,#boids do
  local co=cocreate(move_boid)
  local c=boids[i]
  add(cors,co)
  coresume(co,c)
 end
 for co in all(cors) do
  if (co and costatus(co)!="dead") then
   coresume(co)
  else
   del(cors,co)
  end
 end
end
```

And also modify the calculation function, adding a new line in the middle:

```
function move_boid(c)
 -- code
 yield()
 -- code
end
```

Just to yield before it's completed.

---

**Update:** another way to do it is reusing coroutines.

```
function _init()
 -- code
 -- create coroutines
 cors={}
 for i=1,#boids do
  local co=cocreate(move_boid)
  local c=boids[i]
  add(cors,co)
  coresume(co,c)
 end
end

function _update()
 foreach(cors,coresume)
end

-- and wrap the move function with a loop
function move_boid(c)
 while true do
  -- code
  yield()
  -- code
  yield()
 end
end
```